# python edge detector - mask the area were it's completly black

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have used canny edge detector on an image.
It detected some areas in the image and other areas it displays nothing.
Now, I want that on the original image it would mask the areas that were completely black.
How can I do it?

I am using python and skimage or opencv (doesn't matter which one)

```
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.morphology import closing
import skimage.io
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = skimage.io.imread("test.jpg",as_grey=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,20))
ax.imshow(img,'gray')
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()

edges = canny(img)

close = closing(edges)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20,20))
ax.imshow(close,'gray')
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

[image: Original Image]
[image: After canny and closing]

Now what I want is that the white part(in the second image) would be the only part that would be displayed in the original image ( Masking )

Comment: Attach sample input and current outputs to make your problem clearer.

Comment: I edited. It should be a simple masking problem

Comment: Would you be comfortable in using opencv ?

Comment: yes opencv is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply a binary mask on a RGB image using:

```
close_BGR = cv2.cvtColor(close, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
# Assuming that the img is of RGB format
masked_image = cv2.min(close_BGR, img)
```